# will change from <iostream.h> to <iostream> cause buffer overflow?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, buffer-overflow

I need to build some old codes I got on my office computer, which has `gcc 4.4.5` installed. I edited the code (deleting .h or adding things like `<cstring>`) in order to bring them up to date so they can be compiled by `gcc 4.4.5`. However, after a seemingly successful compile the binary file gives out buffer overflow every time I run it. But the code runs with no error on my computer at home (`gcc 4.1.2`). So is it possible the change I made caused this error? I am not sure since I am not really a programmer.

Comment: It's possible the newer glibc you use have a more aggressive malloc/free (that are used internally from new/delete) that reuse more often freed memory blocks, and that there is some part of the program that is using memory that should be free. So `int *a = something; delete a; *a = 0;`

Answer (score 9):

Far more likely is that the original code was buggy in some way (undefined behaviour, buffer overflows and so on) but the old compiler created (or the old library contained) code that was more tolerant of these issues <sup>(a)</sup>.

I'm afraid you will probably have to go and fix (or get someone to fix) the root cause of the problem. My question to you would be: "if you don't consider yourself a programmer, why are you editing the code and rebuilding it?".

My mother's not a coder either but she doesn't go around tinkering in the Linux kernel :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Sometimes undefined behaviour actually *works!* That's actually its most annoying aspect. Far better that it would fail all the time so that we'd fix more problems before unleashing them on our poor customers. But, even when it works, that doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: +1 for `My mother's not a coder either but she doesn't go around tinkering in the Linux kernel :-)` .. Good one!